# Is there a way to pre-populate the operating system's page table for a large Rust allocation?

Tags: memory-management, rust, page-tables

If you try allocate a large chunk of memory using any of Rust's memory allocation mechanisms (including nightly `alloc_api`) you cannot pre-populate the page table i.e. you cant recreate the MAP_POPULATE option of mmap. Instead, I just use `libc::mmap` when I need to allocate large areas of memory.

Is there another way to pre-populate the page table in Rust other than looping through a `Vec<usize>` or `Vec<SomeTypeOfPageSize>` and triggering page faults?

As [pointed out by @FlorianWeimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221232/is-there-a-way-to-pre-populate-the-operating-systems-page-table-for-a-large-rus#comment77409731_45221232), there are platform specific ways of doing this. I will scan the Rust RFCs to see if the new allocator API includes any pre-populate options.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of speedup do you see with such a pre-population?

Comment: @Shepmaster: As someone working in HFT, my typical answer is that it's not so much the throughput than the predictability of the latency. A single page fault will cause a long tail distribution in the latency (over many executions) that is really irking, as in up to a factor 100x/1000x over the median.

Comment: To add to what @MatthieuM. said it is more about controlling the latency during startup. Over the course of the lifetime of the program it makes no difference (assuming you have eventually filled the page table). But when doing millions of packets per second any blocking behaviour that involves a interrupt/system call is very costly and can result in packets being dropped until the page table is populated

Comment: Could you just use `mlockall`?

Comment: Thanks @FlorianWeimer I'll use that for now.

Comment: I assume that you are going to have a platform-specific answer, so it might be worth adding yours to the question.

Comment: Besides controlling latency, there's also the value in attributing execution cost. Pre-population would cleanly separate 'memory allocation' from the rest of your computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could invoke `mlockall` if you can afford to pre-populate *everything*.  This should work on GNU/Linux and on systems which implement the POSIX Realtime (Process Memory Locking) extensions.

Whether this is acceptable really depends on your application.